# Python Library in C# is possible?

Tags: python, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dll

```
import pyodbc
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def connect_to_database(server, database, username, password):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        f'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'
    )
    return conn

def fetch_text_data(conn, sql_query):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    text_data = [row.Message for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    return text_data

def extract_ngrams(text_data, n_gram_range=(2, 2), stop_words="english"):
    count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=n_gram_range, stop_words=stop_words).fit(text_data)
    candidates = count.get_feature_names_out()
    return candidates

def main():
    server = 'server'
    database = 'database '
    username = 'username '
    password = 'password '
    sql_query = "my_sp"
    
    conn = connect_to_database(server, database, username, password)
    text_data = fetch_text_data(conn, sql_query)
    conn.close()
    
    candidates = extract_ngrams(text_data)
    
    for candidate in candidates:
        print(candidate)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to somehow use this code in c# dotnet core mvc/console application. I tried using built in C# Nuget like ML.Net, etc but didn't got an accurate output as I got with this code, I want to extract phrases from the strings which I pass from a database table's column.
Could I do something like making a dll and use this function or any other way to achieve of what I want to do

Comment: IronPython? But: *why* do you want to use python here? This should be trivial to migrate to .net, no? Most of this is just SQL Server data access: that's two lines with Dapper, and one of those is creating the connection from your connection string ...

Comment: Easiest is probably to just call it using [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0). But a rewrite would be the better long term solution. The AI code is likely using some native library, so figure out what library it is using and how it is called, and do the same from c#.